# Change MAMP password to none

Tags: passwords, mamp

How can i use empty password in MAMP?
I tried the command:
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
and edited the config php file but empty password seems not working..(every other password works fine).
What can i do to use empty password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third party app that runs Apache & MySQL from MAMP without asking for a password each time. It’s quite secure because it uses a stored password locked in the Keychain. It also quits Apache & MySQL when you quit the app itself.

Here is how to use it:

Open the Keychain Access app and click ‘+’ to add a new item. Call the item ‘MAMP’ and enter the account name and password that you use to log in to your Mac.
Download and launch the MAMP No Password app

App is [here](http://www.46palermo.com/blog/run-mamp-without-password-easy-way/).

Comment: Done, now can you remove the downvotes - I answered the question.